# how to safely handle passing parameters to a jenkins build function in groovy script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a funtion in my jenkins groovy script like so:

def build(String p1, String p2, String p3) {

```
    script.stage('Build') {
        try {
            script.sh "./gradlew -Pversion='${currentVersion}' clean build"
        } finally {
            script.step([$class: 'JacocoPublisher', classPattern: p1, exclusionPattern: p2, execPattern: p3])
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I handle the case where a project's jenkins file doesn't pass any arguments to this function? I tried to put if conditions to check if these parameters are empty/null but that gave me the following error in the console output in jenkins:

`org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put defaults like so:

`def build(String p1='', String p2='**/classes', String p3='**/**.exec')`

Worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist the method call in jenkins scripts approval
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

Comment: No.

In general, that's what a "Scripts not permitted to use" error means.

However, when you get that error about `groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod`, what it means is "you tried to invoke a method on a class that doesn't have that method". It's a bad interaction between groovy's behavior with methods that aren't there and Jenkins's security sandbox.

In this case, I believe that the error was being thrown because without defaults specified there was no 0-arg "build" function.